# insertImage via getFilebyID suddenly stopped working

Tags: google-apps-script

I wrote a script months ago and it worked just fine but 2 days ago it stopped placing images. The var name with "url" is misleading seeing I am not using a URL by getting the file by ID.

That part of the script goes is suddenly haywire is:

```
var icon = finalDisplayArray[i][0]; (Im looping to place the images in this array.)

var iconURL = DriveApp.getFileById(icon);
```

//Logger.log tells me the above code does give me the valid name of the .jpg file here so it appears Google has the image ready to go

// THE BELOW IS WHERE IT BUGS OUT

```
ssDisplay.insertImage(iconURL, columnCounter, rowCounter);
```

// ERROR MSG: Exception: The image could not be inserted. Please verify it is valid and try again.

I haven't been using GAS for that long but is it normal for a program to suddenly quit working like this when it worked fine for months?  The "columncounter", etc, is just me placing smaller icons in a row and then columsn if the row gets too long.  Thought it might be since I'm using my company's email and the permissions maybe reset but all the file sharing, etc, is what it's always been.

Comment: From your error message, when you check your `iconURL`, what result did you obtain? Because `var iconURL = DriveApp.getFileById(icon);` is not the URL. It's a file object. For example, when you change `ssDisplay.insertImage(iconURL, columnCounter, rowCounter);` to `ssDisplay.insertImage(DriveApp.getFileById(icon).getBlob(), columnCounter, rowCounter);`, what result will you obtain? But, if I misunderstood your situation, I apologize.

Comment: Yeah, my apologies, it's NOT a URL I'm getting, it's the actual file:

iconURL is 7185364490_icon.jpg

I'm basically grabbing the image from the online director and placing it.   Everything worked fine for months now.  I originally WAS trying use the URL but was running errors when first programming it, found the "grabFilebyId" in a program for Google Docs and used it in Google Sheets just fine but never changed the var name from "url" so thus it's 100% misleading what I'm doing here.

Comment: Thank you for replying. I have to apologize for my poor English skill. When you confirmed my comment, what result did you obtain?

Comment: Same thing: Exception: The image could not be inserted. Please verify it is valid and try again

Sorry my brain is fried, been working all day ;)

it's weird because its showing the actual .jpg name, thus it should have the picture, but refuses now to actually place the image into my sheet.

Comment: Thank you for replying. I have to apologize for my poor English skill again. I would like to correctly understand your reply. In your reply, when you test `ssDisplay.insertImage(DriveApp.getFileById(icon).getBlob(), columnCounter, rowCounter);`, an error of `Exception: The image could not be inserted.` occurs. Is my understanding correct?

Comment: Yes, and it's NOT you, it is me!!!  My brain is going on 15 hours of working so it wants to quit.  Yes, that is the error message it's giving me.

I am asking:
    Logger.log("iconURL is "+iconURL);
    Logger.log("columCounter is "+columnCounter);
    Logger.log("rowCounter is "+rowCounter)

And it's telling me:
iconURL is 3473720253_icon.jpg
columCounter is 1
rowCounter is 1

So technically it should my "ssDisplay.insertImage(iconURL,columnCounter,rowCounter)" should be:
ssDisplay.insertImage(3473720253_icon.jpg,1,1)

It SHOULD be working!!!

Comment: Thank you for replying. I have to apologize for my poor English skill again. Unfortunately, from your reply, I couldn't understand about the result you tested my suggestion. When you tested my suggestion, what result did you obtain?

Comment: Exception: The image could not be inserted. Please verify it is valid and try again.

I'm getting the same error message

Comment: Thank you for replying. I have to apologize for my poor English skill again. I would like to correctly understand your reply. In your reply, when you test `ssDisplay.insertImage(DriveApp.getFileById(icon).getBlob(), columnCounter, rowCounter);`, an error of `Exception: The image could not be inserted.` occurs. Is my understanding correct?

Comment: @Michael, the issue most likely is your `iconURL` is not a blob or a url which the `insertImage` supports. Provide the url by using `iconURL.getUrl()` on the `insertImage` command or `iconURL.getBlob()` which Tanaike recommended

Comment: @Tanaike yes, that is correct

Comment: Thank you for replying. In that case, I'm worried that your image file might not be able to be used for `insertImage`. But I'm not sure about it because I cannot know your actual image file. I apologize for this. For example, when you use other sample image, what result did you obtain? Or, if you can provide the image for correctly replicating your current issue, I can check it. How about this?

Comment: @OctaviaSima sorry I am not sure what a "blob" is!  From what I can tell the "var iconURL = DriveApp.getFileById(icon)" is grabbing the actual .jpg file but then throws me the error.  What I do not understand is it was playing images perfect until 2 days ago when it just stopped working even though I did not touch anything in the program

Comment: @Tanaike it's a simple 'jpg' image off my company's server.  I am just confused because I have been using this for months and its been placing images perfect with no problem but 2 days ago it just stopped.  Nothing changed on my end from what I can tell.

Comment: Thank you for replying. I have to apologize my poor skill. Unfortunately, from your reply of `it's a simple 'jpg' image off my company's server. I am just confused because I have been using this for months and its been placing images perfect with no problem but 2 days ago it just stopped. Nothing changed on my end from what I can tell.`, I cannot understand the data of your image. So I cannot correct answer for avoiding your current issue. So, I asked about the sample image for correctly replicating your current issue. I deeply apologize for my poor skill again.